# What are the common features to identify Brute-Force attack from Apache log file?

Tags: attacks, brute-force, log-analysis, regex

There are various methods to find attack patterns for different types of attacks. Apache-scalp is one such tool, but the rule set is not available to find the brute-force attack pattern via regular expression. I would love to know the different regular expressions available for detecting brute-force attacks from Apache log file.

Comment: What kind of brute-force attack are you talking about? Do you mean attacks against your web application?

Comment: Your question is a bit vague. I don't think regexp are what you need, but with so few informations to work with... could you elaborate please ? Why do you need regexp only ? Don't you have a software to handle your logs and agregate them ?

Comment: finding bruteforce patterns from apache log is rather vague?what kind of bruteforce are you talking about?login credentials,directory bruteforce or common fuzzing?

Comment: @ViliusPovilaika Yes, attacks against web application so that the log of that attack is stored in access.log file. I want to find out through log file that the brute force attack is tried in my web application.

Comment: @Kaël I am trying to test the apache log file so that the brute force attack is being tried. Yes, there are other methods too for testing brute force attack from log, though I wanna know it via regexp also.

Comment: @VipulNair For this time, I wanna concentrate on login credentials & common fuzzing.

Comment: like you said simple analysis of logs should give you a good idea of attack.Common strings such as union query can be seen in the apache log when an attacker tries sql injection.This should get you started https://resources.infosecinstitute.com/log-analysis-web-attacks-beginners-guide/#gref

Comment: yes, this apache-scalp does not include brute-force attack

Answer (score 0):

You can run `grep` against Apache access log searching for your login page, use `awk` to carve out the source IP address then use `wc` to count how many times a source IP hit your login page.

That would be a simple way to check for brute-force login attacks from a single source.

Comment: awk does *grepping* too... no need to `grep | awk`.

Comment: ... can you provide an example?

Comment: `awk '/login.php/ {print $1}' access_log | sort | uniq -c | sort -gr | head -10` will print the top 10 IP addresses that most accessed `login.php`.

Answer (score 0):

#### High volume of traffic:

`^(\S+) .+ .+ \[.*\] "(POST|GET) .+ HTTP/\d\.\d" 401 \d+ "-" ".+"$`

This regular expression matches any HTTP POST or GET request that returns a 401 error and is made from the same IP address, indicating a potential brute-force attack.

#### Unusual user agents:

`^.*"(POST|GET).*HTTP.*" 401 .*"(python|curl|wget|libwww-perl|python-requests|httrack|HTTPie)"\s*$`

This regular expression matches any HTTP POST or GET request that returns a 401 error and is made by a user agent associated with automated tools like Python, curl, wget, etc.

#### Failed login attempts:

`^.*"(POST|GET).*HTTP.*" 401 .*"[^"]*"\s*$`

#### Multiple login attempts:

`^.*"(POST|GET).*HTTP.*" 40[13] .*"[^"]*"\s*$`